# ¿Cómo evitar el auto guardado del login con PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

Hola tengo un sencillo login

Mi código:

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
 header("Location: home.php");
 exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
 
 $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
 $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
 
 $email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
 $password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);
 
 $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT user_id, email, password FROM tbl_users WHERE email='$email'");
 $row=$query->fetch_array();
 
 $count = $query->num_rows; // if email/password are correct returns must be 1 row
 
 if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) && $count==1) {
  $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: home.php");
 } else {
  $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
     <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
    </div>";
 }
 $DBcon->close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a style="color:#fff;" class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Html-512.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
   Sommer
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="color:#fff;" class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a style="color:#fff;" class="nav-link disabled" href="#">En Desarrollo</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav><br><br>
<body>

<div class="signin-form">

 <div class="container">
     
        
       <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="login-form">
      
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2><hr />
        
        <?php
  if(isset($msg)){
   echo $msg;
  }
  ?>
        
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="email" required autocomplete="off" />
        <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
       
      <hr />
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-login" id="btn-login">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Iniciar Sesion
   </button> 
            
            <a href="register.php" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;">Soy nuevo</a>
            
        </div>  
        
        
      
      </form>

    </div>
    
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi problema es que vean esta imagen : 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se queda aun guardado los usuarios, lo que me gustaría hacer es evitar eso, claro podría eliminar mis cookies de chrome y listo pero yo quisiera evitar que se guarden las cookies en PHP.
¿Alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer esto en PHP?

Comment: Eso es un funcionamiento a nivel de navegador por lo que dudo que PHP tenga algo para evitarlo. De hecho no es cosa de cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Hace unos días tenía el mismo problema, el detallito era con HTML, de todas formas te dejo lo que encontre hace unos días en una página de WordPress:

-> [Enlace Directo](https://andrezgz.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/evitar-que-el-navegador-solicite-recordar-los-datos-de-acceso-en-formulario-de-login/)

Comment: Las preguntas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad. Si la página enlazada cambia o se rompe el enlace, entonces la pregunta deja de ser útil y tener sentido. Añade las partes claves del artículo enlazado (manteniendo el enlace como fuente/referencia).

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta del usuario @drtechno

Traduccida:
La única manera que puedo obtener firefox, borde e Internet Explorer para desactivar autocompletar es añadir autocomplete = "false" en mi declaración de formulario como:

```html
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468288/input-type-password-dont-let-browser-remember-the-password)

Comment: Eso no evita tu problema, simplemente no permite seleccionar valores anteriores pero las contraseñas y usuarios se siguen guardando.

Comment: Puedes añadir el `autocomplete="off"` en la etiqueta de formulario para que se aplique a todos los campos. Aunque puede que haya navegadores que se la salten en algunos casos.